# How BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT instantiate serialize function for all used archives?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

From [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#instantiation) of boots/serialization:

> ...BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID explicitly instantiates the class serialization code for all archive classes used by the program.

I looked into the source code and found this:

```
#define BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(T)                      \
    namespace boost {                                        \
    namespace archive {                                      \
    namespace detail {                                       \
    namespace extra_detail {                                 \
    template<>                                               \
    struct init_guid< T > {                                  \
        static guid_initializer< T > const & g;              \
    };                                                       \
    guid_initializer< T > const & init_guid< T >::g =        \
        ::boost::serialization::singleton<                   \
            guid_initializer< T >                            \
        >::get_mutable_instance().export_guid();             \
    }}}}                                                     \
/**/

#define BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2(T, K)          \
namespace boost {                              \
namespace serialization {                      \
template<>                                     \
struct guid_defined< T > : boost::mpl::true_ {}; \
template<>                                     \
inline const char * guid< T >(){                 \
    return K;                                  \
}                                              \
} /* serialization */                          \
} /* boost */                                  \
/**/

#define BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(T, K)                                  \
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2(T, K)                                          \
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(T)                                        \
/**/
```

I understand, how `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2` works - it defines template indicating that given class defines GUID and stores this string.

But how BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT does work? I'm reading it over and over again, but I cannot see how it *explicitly instantiates class serialization code for all archive classes*...

I wrote following example, it works as expected, but when I debugged it, it was too complicated structure, I still don't understand.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

#define UNUSED(i_param) ((void)i_param)

class Base
{
public:

    Base(int i_baseValue) :
        m_baseValue(i_baseValue)
    {

    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {

    }

    virtual void print() = 0;

protected:

    int m_baseValue;

private:

    friend class ::boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        UNUSED(file_version);

        ar & m_baseValue;
    }

};

class A : public Base
{
public:

    A(int i_aValue, int i_baseValue) :
        Base(i_baseValue),
        m_aValue(i_aValue)
    {

    }

    A() :
        Base(-1),
        m_aValue(-1)
    {

    }

    ~A()
    {

    }

    void print()
    {
        ::std::cout << "A, base: " << m_baseValue << ", a: " << m_aValue << ::std::endl;
    }

private:

    friend class ::boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        UNUSED(file_version);

        ar & ::boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar & m_aValue;
    }


    int m_aValue;
};

class B : public Base
{
public:

    B(int i_bValue, int i_baseValue) :
        Base(i_baseValue),
        m_bValue(i_bValue)
    {

    }

    B() :
        Base(-2),
        m_bValue(-2)
    {

    }

    ~B()
    {

    }

    void print()
    {
        ::std::cout << "B, base: " << m_baseValue << ", b: " << m_bValue << ::std::endl;
    }

private:

    friend class ::boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        UNUSED(file_version);

        ar & ::boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar & m_bValue;
    }


    int m_bValue;
};

typedef ::boost::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr;

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Base, "base")
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(A, "A")
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(B, "B")

void printAll(::std::vector<BasePtr>& data)
{
    std::cout << " --- " << ::std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        data[i]->print();
    }
    std::cout << " --- " << ::std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ::std::stringstream stream;

    {
        ::std::vector<BasePtr> data;
        data.push_back(BasePtr(new A(10, 20)));
        data.push_back(BasePtr(new B(33, 44)));

        printAll(data);

        ::boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(stream);

        ar & data;
    }

    //::std::cout << "Data:\n" << stream.str() << "\n";

    {
        ::std::vector<BasePtr> data;

        stream.seekg(0);
        ::boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(stream);

        ar & data;

        printAll(data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 --- 
A, base: 20, a: 10
B, base: 44, b: 33
 --- 
 --- 
A, base: 20, a: 10
B, base: 44, b: 33
 ---
```

Which works as expected.

**Note:** some people might ask why I want to know this. I don't think it's important, but it's because I need some serialization code, however boost is not usable for me for a few reasons. So I'm investigating whether I can modify boost to my needs (for example by implementing custom archive + some core code modifications) or whether it would be better to implement something own. For both cases, I would like to know, how it works so I could determine whether it's usable in my case or whether I could mimic this behaviour. Third reason is simply curiosity and hunger for knowledge.

---

**Update:**

After more hours of digging into this I found that it's here (from boost):

```
template<class T>
struct guid_initializer
{
    void export_guid(mpl::false_) const {
        // generates the statically-initialized objects whose constructors
        // register the information allowing serialization of T objects
        // through pointers to their base classes.
        instantiate_ptr_serialization((T*)0, 0, adl_tag());
    }
    void export_guid(mpl::true_) const {
    }
    guid_initializer const & export_guid() const {
        BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(boost::is_polymorphic< T >::value);
        // note: exporting an abstract base class will have no effect
        // and cannot be used to instantitiate serialization code
        // (one might be using this in a DLL to instantiate code)
        //BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(! boost::serialization::is_abstract< T >::value);
        export_guid(boost::serialization::is_abstract< T >());
        return *this;
    }
};
```

while registering an archive is handled here:

```
// This function gets called, but its only purpose is to participate
// in overload resolution with the functions declared by
// BOOST_SERIALIZATION_REGISTER_ARCHIVE, below.
template <class Serializable>
void instantiate_ptr_serialization(Serializable*, int, adl_tag ) {}

// The function declaration generated by this macro never actually
// gets called, but its return type gets instantiated, and that's
// enough to cause registration of serialization functions between
// Archive and any exported Serializable type.  See also:
// boost/serialization/export.hpp
# define BOOST_SERIALIZATION_REGISTER_ARCHIVE(Archive)                  \
namespace boost { namespace archive { namespace detail {                \
                                                                        \
template <class Serializable>                                           \
BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME _ptr_serialization_support<Archive, Serializable>::type  \
instantiate_ptr_serialization( Serializable*, Archive*, adl_tag );              \
                                                                        \
```

however I still don't see how it works. From documentation I only understand the usage, not principle how it works. You need to register your `Archive` implementation and then exporting the derived classes will create serialization method specialization for each end every registered archive. How?

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at our port of this functionality in [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal), a C++11 serialization library with a similar interface to boost serialization (see details/polymorphic_impl in particular).  It'd take me a while to remember exactly how everything works, but we went through pains to comment everything.  The gist of all of this is that some compiler tricks are used to instantiate templates that are never explicitly instantiated, allowing a binding to be created between all registered archives and all registered polymorphic types.

Comment: @Azoth Thank you, I'll check it out (regrettably, I don't have time now). It's nice that you commented it - it's quite rare...